# Loss of syntax coloring in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, color-scheme

Recently, Visual Studio 2012's syntax coloring has mostly stopped working. The jade coloring for class declarations and the dark blue for "using" or "this." still apply, but the yellow for System.*** or method calls no longer apply.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic; <- (should be yellow)
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {    ^- (normally colored)
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); <- (should be orange)
        }
    }
}
```

The only customization I've made is applying the Dark theme to VS. So far I've tried running the devenv /setup and /resetuserdata with no success, tried repairing, tried fully uninstalling (normal control panel + /force with devenv) and reinstalling, but still have no syntax coloring. This is all under the C# environment.

Any tips on getting the proper coloring back is appreciated. As small as it is, it's driving me crazy.

Comment: Try applying blue theme and see if that bring the syntax coloring back. If so then you can get the black there from somebody else.

Comment: No luck :( The lack of color exists across the built in Dark, Blue, and Light themes. I don't understand what could've caused it to disappear, when I had first installed it (first ever), the coloring was all there like I described in the OP. But now, it's just gone.